# Port forwarding for ssh on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I need some help troubleshooting my problem. I am trying to ssh into my pi from a non lan pc. I have port forwarded before and did not expect it to be this difficult. Here is what I have done:

1: Set up port forwarding on my router, the Asus rt-ac66u. These are the configurations: [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXtcZ.png) (Sorry not enough reputation here to post the picture )

2:Restarting the router.

3:Turning on ssh on the pi. I am running raspbian lite(no desktop) version 4.9. I can access the pi over ssh on lan.

4:Google searching "what is my ip" to find my ip. Use this ip and the port in step one to ssh to the pi using putty. I get a timeout error.

I posted the question here on the [raspberry pi stackexchange.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73179/port-forwarding-for-ssh-router-issue) I was told that it could be the ISP blocking the connections. If it is the ISP how would I confirm that this is the issue and if so fix it?

Comment: I don't think it is your ISP. Have you done anything to troubleshoot your firewall rules on the pi? Maybe it only allows connections from your local network. How about tcpdump to see where the connection is breaking down?

Comment: Your ISP may be using CGNAT which is why you can't access it from outside your LAN. I had a similar problem with my port forwarding. Hope this post I've linked below helps you. 
[Which IP address do I use to access my server?](https://superuser.com/questions/1244595/which-ip-address-do-i-use-to-access-my-server)

Comment: I have done some digging and it seems that the pi has the firewall off by default. I don't think it is CGNAT. When I google "what is my ip" it matches what is listed on my router(from reading your link that seems to be one symptom).

Comment: Can you install wireshark on sometyhing. If so then port forward to the device with wireshark and ensure you can see the packets coming in after port translation also if you can setup a SSH server confirm you can see packets going out and going back out.  If the ISP is blocking , then the only way is to get  them to stop or try different ports. Since essentially you are trying the second that seems unlikely

Comment: You can use a service like https://tunnelin.com which will forward your connection through a secure tunnel and allow you to connect (ssh, vnc, https etc.) to your device over the internet. It does not require any configuration and not depend on your (ISP) network topology.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [web service called dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com/) is more or less easy to install and free for one device. After installing you can access to the CLI via company web or native Android or IOS applications.