# Troubleshooting an SSH connection to a home network computer

Tags: networking, router, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have set a Raspberry Pi on a home network with a Mercusys MW325R wireless router.  The connection is via WiFi.  On the router I have set a "virtual server" (which I imagine is the same as port forwarding, as there is no explicit forwarding option) to forward port 2454 to 22 on the Raspberry Pi.

I can ssh into the Raspberry Pi from the local network.  However, when I try to ssh into the computer from outside, using the IP address revealed by What Is My IP etc., the connection times out.  SSH check websites indicate an error in connecting to the server.

The same problem happens if I change the external port higher (tried 60051) or lower (tried 80 and 22).  The Pi's SSH logs don't seem to show any connection attempts and `ssh -vvvv` in the client system only shows "connection timed out."

Nmap from [Pentest-tools](http://www.pentest-tools.com) says that the port is "filtered."

I've tried reading as much as I can about this and cannot find any clear answer.  Where would one begin troubleshooting a failure like this?  Is it my ISP that's blocking things?

Traceroute:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.608 ms  3.130 ms  3.409 ms
 2  103.70.xxx.xxx (xxx)  2.469 ms  3.329 ms  3.568 ms
 3  103.70.xxx.xxx (xxx)  5.314 ms  5.652 ms  7.900 ms
 4  45.120.248.10 (45.120.248.10)  10.067 ms  10.351 ms  10.315 ms
 5  108.170.251.97 (108.170.251.97)  12.015 ms 108.170.251.113 (108.170.251.113)  12.335 ms 108.170.251.97 (108.170.251.97)  12.307 ms
 6  72.14.238.41 (72.14.238.41)  15.085 ms 74.125.37.149 (74.125.37.149)  7.442 ms 74.125.37.137 (74.125.37.137)  8.017 ms
 7  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  4.872 ms  5.950 ms  6.182 ms
```

Comment: Check if you're behind a [Carrier-grade NAT](https://superuser.com/q/1244595/432690).

Comment: It's confusing, as the router lists its own WAN IP address as 174.175.175.xxx - which looks (given its neat symmetry) as if it is a private IP address, but from what I can see is not in the private range. But it is also not the public IP that any other service lists (e.g. whatismyip etc.)

Comment: What happens when you try to connect from the outside to this WAN IP you've found?

Comment: When I try from an ssh check website, I get the same message re an error in connecting

Comment: Could you post result of `traceroute 8.8.8.8` (or `tracert 8.8.8.8` if you on windows) from your LAN

Comment: Posted in main question

Comment: That's something unclear, your public IP 174.175.175.xxx belong to Comcast, who known as one who doesn't use "carrier-grade NAT" as Kamil suggested. The strange things is that first hop IP doesn't belong to comcast. You masked `103.70.xxx.xxx` for privacy, so could you do `whois` with real IP from first hop `whois 103.70.xxx.xxx`. Does it belong to your ISP? It looks to me as this IP belong to some Asia/Australia blocks

Comment: That's doubly odd, as I live in India and the ISP is in Delhi. The IP in that first step maps to the correct ISP - Gayatri Communications.

Comment: I suggest you to borrow for testing from some1 a router or connect computer directly to a modem and test again your public IP address. In recent years I saw a lot of hacked vulnerable routers that doing weird things